# Swift: Trouble setting value of data using Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The database in my firebase database is currently saved in this manner:

```
{
  "messages" : {
    "-KOxK41dRvVOjXq0CgZ0" : {
      "date" : "2016-08-12 05:58:12 +0000",
      "location" : "Seattle, WA",
      "score" : 0,
      "senderId" : "LylxZpPcmQgSFLGmpemKJDHvqQX2",
      "text" : "Yo"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to implement a way for a user to press a button and the score will go up. I thought I could just use Firebase's `setValue` code to just add one to the score value for each message.

Here is the code that I used for that:

```
super.collectionView(collectionView, didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        let data = self.messages[indexPath.item]
        print("They tapped: "  + (data.text) + "- " + (data.senderDisplayName))
        data.score += 1
        messageRef.child("messages.score").setValue(data.score)
        print(data.score)
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
```

I am assuming this is because I have "messages.score" as my child when I should be putting something else in there. I looked through the Firebase documentation but couldn't figure out what to put.

Does anybody have any idea how I can fix my problem?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I tried this piece of code:

```
var rootRef : FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let senderID = data.senderId
        rootRef.child("messages").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snap) in
            if snap.exists(){
                for each in snap as! [String:AnyObject]{
                    let postID = each.key as! String
                    if let messagesDict = each.value as! [String:AnyObject]{
                        if senderID == messageDict["senderId"]{
                            //Checking for the senderID of the user so that you only increment the score of that particular message post
                            let userScore = messageDict["score"] as! Int
                            userScore = userScore + 1
                            rootRef.child("messages").child(postID).child("score").setValue(userScore)
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            }
        })
```

But am getting the following errors in the editor:

[image: errors]

Comment: Use "score" instead of "messages.score".

Comment: Alsi better to do this in a transaction to avoid a race condition with multiple writers trying to set the score at the same time.

Comment: How would I be able to do a transaction?

Comment: What is `messageRef`?An post your JSON tree not just a part of it.

Comment: @Dravidian well I have two ref's:     `var rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()` and 
    `var messageRef: FIRDatabaseReference!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :-

```
    let rootRef : FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var senderID = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid

    rootRef.child("messages").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snap) in

        if snap.exists(){
            if let messagesDict = snap.value! as? [String : AnyObject]
            {
                for each in messagesDict as [String : AnyObject]{

                    let postID = each.0
                    if let messageDict = each.1 as? [String:AnyObject]{
                        if senderID == messageDict["senderId"] as! String{
                            //Checking for the senderID of the user so that you only increment the score of that particular message post
                            var userScore = messageDict["score"] as! Int
                            userScore = userScore + 1
                            rootRef.child("messages").child(postID).child("score").setValue(userScore)
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: That ran with no errors! All went well except I think it's an infinite loop haha the points never stop adding up after I tap the button unless I quit the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120943/discussion-between-dravidian-and-ahad-sheriff).